# codeship/rails test database configuration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration, codeship

I'm attempting to use codeship for CI and am getting a strange error:

The Error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a string to ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection for a configuration lookup is deprecated, please pass a symbol (:"") instead. (called from block in tsort_each at /home/rof/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226)
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: '' database is not configured. Available: ["development", "test", "production"]
```

Setup commands in codeship:

```
rvm use 2.2.0 --install
bundle install
export RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rake db:schema:load <----- error begins here, tried adding RAILS_ENV=test which didn't resolve
```

my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: appname_development
  username: postgres
  password: postgres


test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: appname_test
  username: postgres
  password: postgres

production:
  database: appname_production
  url: <%= ENV['HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK_URL'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV['DB_POOL'] || ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5 %>
```

Comment: Ahoy, Marko from the Codeship crew here, did you already send us a support request at support@codeship.com including a link to the failing build. Your setup looks good, but I can help more if you contact us on Codeship directly.

Comment: Hi Marko, I had not - I figured I was botching something on our end.  Will open a request now to get it sorted out